# Office.js wildcard search with special characters crashes Word Online but not installed MSWord

Tags: search, ms-word, wildcard, office-js

Wildcard searches such as the example detailed in the following article crashes Word Online, whilst working as expected for the installed version of MSWord

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/search-option-guidance

I'm searching for the following text:
'Payment of invoices by Sponsor shall be made within thirty (30'

The text may or may not be broken across line/section breaks.  Therefore I'm performing a wildcard search as follows:
'Payment?of?invoices?by?Sponsor?shall?be?made?within?thirty?(30'

This causes Word-Online to crash the browser.

Interestingly the following works in both Word Online and MSWord:

'Payment of invoices by Sponsor shall be made within thirty (30) days'

'Payment?of?invoices?by?Sponsor?shall?be?made?within?thirty?(30)?days'

There appears to be a problem with un-closed parenthesis in the wildcard expression.

Following the article above, it suggests that the parenthesis should be escaped with square brackets.  The following worked in MSWord but crashed Word-Online:

'Payment?of?invoices?by?Sponsor?shall?be?made?within?thirty?[(]30'

Even stranger is that the square brackets escapement only works if the last character is being escaped.

This works in both MSWord and Word-Online:

'include?intangible?things?[(]'

whereas this only works in MSWord and crashes Word-Online

include?intangible?things?[(]e

The example pattern in the article above ' [ * ] * ' crashes Word Online, whilst working as expected in MSWord.

```
input = 'include?intangible?things?[(]e';
const { Word } = window;
Word.run(context => {
    const { body } = context.document;
    const searchResults = body.search(input, {
        matchCase: false,
        ignoreSpace: true,
        ignorePunct: true,
        matchWildcards: true
    });
    context.load(searchResults);
    return context
        .sync()
        .then(() => {

        })
        .catch(error => {            
        });
});
```

Both MSWord and Word Online should behave the same when both are executed through the Office.js API.

This looks like a bug in Word Online.  I would speculate that it's probably something to do with url encoding.

Either that, or I'm not encoding my input pattern correctly when the target is Word Online.  In which case the article referenced above needs updating to detail what the Word Online 'escapes' are for the special characters.

Curiously the escaping [ ] brackets are themselves special characters.

[Word Online crashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXiPJ.png)

Comment: I filed a bug for this yesterday, I am having the same issue. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1141

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer this, but it solves the Word Online crashing issue and the un-closed parenthesis problem in one hit.  I'm replacing all the special characters in my search string with '?' characters.  This might result in a misidentified piece of text, but the likelihood is low enough for this to not be a problem for what I'm trying to achieve.

```
function replaceSpecialCharacters(input) {
    let modifiedInput = '';
    const specialCharacters = ['[', ']', '(', ')', '{', '}', '*', '?', '<', '>', '!', '@'];
    [...input].forEach(c => {
        if (specialCharacters.includes(c)) {
            modifiedInput = `${modifiedInput}?`;
        } else {
            modifiedInput = `${modifiedInput}${c}`;
        }
    });
    return modifiedInput;
}
```